# Не применяется рефлексия в android studio

Tags: java, android, рефлексия

Всем привет. 
У меня стоит следующая задача, написание rest клиента для приложения в андроид.
Проблема возникла при попытке использования нестандартных методов, начал искать как в HttpURLConnection добавить свой метод. Нашел следующее решение:

```
private static void allowMethods(String... meth) {
    try {
        System.out.println("RRR=" + HttpURLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("method"));
        System.out.println("RRR=" + HttpURLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("methods"));

        System.out.println(getAllModelFields(HttpURLConnection.class));

        Field methodsField = HttpURLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("methods");

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(methodsField, methodsField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        methodsField.setAccessible(true);

        String[] oldMethods = (String[]) methodsField.get(null);
        Set<String> methodsSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(oldMethods));
        methodsSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(meth));
        String[] newMethods = methodsSet.toArray(new String[0]);

        methodsField.set(null/*static field*/, newMethods);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }catch (IllegalAccessException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Далее в своей программе вызываю этот метод, передаю туда название нужного мне нового метода, и далее по стандарту пишу создание и выполнение запроса с указанием моего метода " con.setRequestMethod("MOVE");"

НО!!!
Когда вставил этот код в android studio, ide сразу сообщила о проблеме, а именно: 
Cannot resolve field 'methods' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection detects reflective access to fields and methods which don't exist or aren't visible
ну и с полем modifiers аналогично.

Попробовал этот же код в IntelliJ IDEA, там код выполняется, правда выдает варнинги.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by main (file:/D:/java/untitled1/out/production/untitled1/) to field java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of main
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

На что можно обратить внимание, куда копать? 
Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Ну, студия предупреждает и что, отклоняет сборку или приложение не работает как надо? В чём проблема - то? Или на Android 9 эти поля попали в [чёрный список](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/runtime/+/master/appcompat/hiddenapi-blacklist.txt) - тогда могу только предложить использовать `OkHttp` или другую сетевую либу, поддерживающую расширенный список методов или добавление своих.

Comment: Проблема в том, что при попытке выполнения рефлексии в указанном ранее методе, вылетает исключение:  java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field methods in class Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection; (declaration of 'java.net.HttpURLConnection' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

Comment: woesss, спасибо. Через OkHttp  все получилось!!!